# Regex pattern to allow all brackets and alphanumeric

Tags: angularjs, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern to accept alphanumeric plus some of the special characters - `(, /'() {[])`

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z _\\\/.,’'\-{[\]}]+$/"
```

- Should allow only Alpha characters [a-zA-Z]
- Allow certain special characters  [_/.,'-{}[]]

Comment: Good one; have in mind you've also included the `\ ` char, but haven't listed it in the "allowed characters" line :). The same goes for `'` and `\``.